# the smallest module of number in IEEE754 (double precision)

Tags: architecture, ieee-754

Let `a =\= b` and `a`  and `b` are representable in double precision of IEEE754.  Find `a` and `b` such that `|a-b|` is minimal.

I know that exponent has `11` bits, and fraction has `52` bits.
However, I can't find `a` and `b`.  Have you any idea ?

Comment: Now tell us what a =\= b means.

Comment: it means different, not (a==b)